# Howto select image from facebook

Tags: facebook

On my website there is possible post image from computer. But I would like also provide user to post image from facebook user album. I can imagine some dialog like "Facebook login" which will open faceook images and provide user to send image from facebook to my application. Does something like that possible? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I assume you have a little experience with facebook api.

1. trigger login FB login window and request `user_photos` permission
2. make a query to facebook to get (all/random/a few) user albums like so `me/albums?fields=id,count`
3. If a key `count` is set, there are photos
4. `(I would collect all IDs of albums containing photos and make a query to facebook with ech one ID)`
5. Then again, query to facebook like so `/%album-id%?fields=photos.fields(images)`
6. Now you have an array of URLs of images which, for example you show to a user and after he selects, you download it and upload to your server

Since you did not request a solid code, I will provide you with at least with a little snippet, or show an illustration how to do that. http://paste2.org/hvGkngIL. (a metod `index`)  (Might not work properly, since I cut it from a PHP framework I work with)